# jquery enable/disable fields based on variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a variable that i am using to disable input fields across all field sets in a page.

```
$("[eventDisabled='true'] input").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

However i need to enable certain input fields that are in some specific div, i have placed those input fields in some other div

When i use below code to enabled them, it is not working

```
$("[eventDisabled='true'] #someotherdiv input").attr('enabled', 'enabled');
```

Any help

Comment: Can you post your html code, or the link if it's online?

Answer (score 0):

One way to suppress inputs within a specific container by using the css psudo-class [:not(selector)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) in your jQuery selector as follows:

```
$('div:not(#someotherdiv) input[eventDisabled=true]')
```

This will select all inputs that has an attribute of eventDisabled with a value of true and that is not a child of a div with an id of someotherdiv

Comment: so should i do something like this to enable it? $('#someotherdiv input[eventDisabled=true]').attr('enabled', 'enabled');

Comment: I would stick to the default behavior of the disabled attribute and keep things simple .  

First disable all input fields
$('input').attr('disabled', true);
Then enable what you need enabled
$('#someotherdiv input').removeAttr('disabled');

Comment: yes but im also doing things like this .off('click') etc, which makes it more complicated to turn it back on